# Facing issue with jqGrid: Row data it's not getting saved, shows in editable mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqgrid

Issue: I am using a custom button to save row data in jqgrid, edited rows still shows in editable mode.

I am a newbie in this & not able to understand where I am going wrong.

Approach:
Used saveparameters on saveRow but successfunc is not getting fired.

My functions:
function Fun_get: This function is getting the data from a system using Fetchxml.
function textFormatter : This function is parsing the fetchxml data.
function PopulateGrid: populating the JqGrid.

My Code snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
<title id="Description">JQGrid Demo.</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link href="jquery.ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery.1.10.2.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="grid.locale.en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var serverUrl = GetGlobalContext().getServerUrl();
  var ltcId;
    function textFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        /// <summary>
        /// Text column formatter
        /// </summary>

        if (cellvalue != null) {
            return cellvalue.value;
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
    function Fun_get() {

        if (window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId() != "" && window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId() != null) {               
                var accountid = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
            }

        var FetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical'>"
            + "<entity name='contact'>"
            + "<attribute name='contactid' alias='ConId'/>"
            + "<attribute name='firstname' alias='FN'/>"
            + "<attribute name='lastname' alias='LN'/>"
            + "<attribute name='emailaddress1' alias='Email'/>"         
            + "<order descending='false' attribute='emailaddress1'/>"
            + "<filter type='and'>"
            + "<condition attribute='parentcustomerid' operator='eq' value='" + accountid + "'></condition>"            
            + "</filter>"
            + "</entity>"
            + "</fetch>";
            //Fetchxml call
            var _oService = new FetchUtil("", serverUrl);
            _oService.Fetch(FetchXml, sendQueryCallBack); 
    }
    function sendQueryCallBack(results) {
        var lastsel;
        var outPutId = "#tbloutput";
        var editlist = [];
        var result1 = results;        

        jQuery(outPutId).jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
        //debugger;
        jQuery(outPutId).jqGrid({
            width: 150,
            datatype: "local",
            colNames: ['First Name','Last Name','Email','ConId'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'FN', width: 100, index: 'FN',editable:true, formatter: textFormatter, sorttype: textFormatter },
            { name: 'LN', width: 100, index: 'LN',editable:true, formatter: textFormatter, sorttype: textFormatter },
            { name: 'Email', width: 100, index: 'Email',editable:true, formatter: textFormatter, sorttype: textFormatter },
            { name: 'ConId', width: 100, index: 'ConId',hidden:true,editable:true, formatter: textFormatter, sorttype: textFormatter }
            ],
            scrollOffset:0,
            rowNum:5,           
            width: 450,
            height: 100,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "CONTACTS",
            editurl: 'clientArray',     
            onSelectRow: function(id){
                //debugger;
                if(id && id!==lastsel)
                {
                    saveparameters = 
                    {
                        "successfunc" : function( response ) {
                                              alert('Row saved');
                                          },
                        "url" : 'clientArray',
                        "extraparam" : {},
                        "aftersavefunc" : function( response ) {
                                              alert('After save');
                                          },
                        "errorfunc": null,
                        "afterrestorefunc" : null,
                        "restoreAfterError" : true,
                        "mtype" : "POST"
                    }
                  jQuery(outPutId).jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel, saveparameters );               
                  lastsel=id;

                }
            }
        });             
        if (result1.length > 0) {
            for (var x = 0; x < result1.length; x++) {              
                jQuery(outPutId).jqGrid('addRowData', x + 1, result1[x].attributes);
            }
        }      

    }
        //To Save the row data
        function save() {
            saveparameters = 
                    {
                        "successfunc" : function( response ) {
                                              alert('Row saved');
                                          },
                        "url" : 'clientArray',
                        "extraparam" : {},
                        "aftersavefunc" : function( response ) {
                                              alert('After save');
                                          },
                        "errorfunc": null,
                        "afterrestorefunc" : null,
                        "restoreAfterError" : true,
                        "mtype" : "POST"
                    }
            var rowIndex = jQuery(tbloutput).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            jQuery(tbloutput).jqGrid('saveRow', rowIndex, saveparameters, 'clientArray');           

        };
        //To Edit the row data
        function edit(){
            var id = jQuery(tbloutput).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            jQuery(tbloutput).jqGrid('editRow',id,false);               
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload=javascript:Fun_get()>
<table id="tbloutput">
<tbody></tbody></table>
<div id="pager" style="height: 30px; font-size: small;"></div></div>
<div>
</br>
<button id="edit" style="border-color: rgb(113, 169, 210); color: white; background-color: rgb(113, 169, 210);" onclick="edit();" type="submit">Edit</button> 
<button id="save" style="border-color: rgb(113, 169, 210); color: white; background-color: rgb(113, 169, 210);" onclick="save();" type="submit">save</button> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Output of jqgrid, showing rows editable]

Comment: For further I have created a simple jqgrid example & for my surprise it's working pretty fine. [Sample Code](http://pastebin.com/u3HXePqm)

Comment: For my surprise same is working only if I use array or json data. I don't know whats wrong with mentioned approach. I will post again if I get the root cause... I request others also to look into it. Thanks..